# Open Numbers application on Mac/iOS using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, ios, macos

We have a website built in .net. One of the pages detects what operating system the user is on and then displays an xls/numbers icon depending on this os.

When the user clicks on the icon, either Excel or Numbers should open with a blank sheet.

This is working fine for microsoft based operating systems, but having no luck with macs/iOS devices.

The code in the .cshtml file calls a controller action to open either application.
This is the current code we're using:

**File.cshtml**

```
// WINDOWS OS
if (ViewBag.os == "windows") {
    <li><a href='@Url.Action("LoadFile", "Footprint", new { os = "windows" }, null)'><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/img/excelicon.png")' width="55px" height="55px" /></a>  </li>                                   

// MAC OR IOS                                            
} else {
  if (ViewBag.os == "mac") {
    <li><a href='@Url.Action("LoadFile", "Footprint", new { os = "mac" }, null)'><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/img/numbersicon.png")' width="55px" height="55px" /></a>  </li>

} else {
  <li><a href='@Url.Action("LoadFile", "Footprint", new { os = "ios" }, null)'><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/img/numbersicon.png")' width="55px" height="55px" /></a>  </li>                                     
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult LoadFile(string os) {

  if (os == "windows") {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("excel.exe", "/m");

  } else {    
    // Open Numbers.app
    ??
  }
  return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Is there a way we can use Process.Start() to open the Numbers.app?
Any other ideas would be awesome!

Thanks in advance,
Kat

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no generally applicable way to launch an application on Mac OS or iOS without downloading and opening a file associated with it.

In fact, your Windows code is also faulty -- it will open an instance of Excel **on the server** when one of these links is clicked, not on the client machine.